# Jacoco code coverage show 0% coverage on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, maven-2, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have read most of the answers available for similar questions but none of those fit to answer my question.

My profile in pom file looks like this:

```
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                            is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                                <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                                    runtime agent. -->
                                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created 
                            after unit tests have been run. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-unit-test</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>surefire-unit-tests</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                                <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is 
                                    true -->
                                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                                <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
                                <skip>false</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Ensures that both integration-test and verify goals of the Failsafe 
                            Maven plugin are executed. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run. -->
                                <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                                <!-- Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests 
                                    property is true -->
                                <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```

When I run my jenkins job with maven goal `clean install -P test-coverage`

I See this in my Jenkins log:

```
`[JaCoCo plugin] Collecting JaCoCo coverage data...
[JaCoCo plugin] **/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec;**/target/classes;**/src/main/java; locations are configured
[JaCoCo plugin] Number of found exec files for pattern **/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec: 0
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched execfiles:  
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched class directories for class-pattern: **/target/classes: 
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched source directories for source-pattern: **/src/main/java: 
[JaCoCo plugin] Loading inclusions files..
[JaCoCo plugin] inclusions: []
[JaCoCo plugin] exclusions: []
[JaCoCo plugin] Thresholds: JacocoHealthReportThresholds [minClass=0, maxClass=0, minMethod=0, maxMethod=0, minLine=0, maxLine=0, minBranch=0, maxBranch=0, minInstruction=0, maxInstruction=0, minComplexity=0, maxComplexity=0]
[JaCoCo plugin] Publishing the results..
[JaCoCo plugin] Loading packages..
[JaCoCo plugin] Done.
[JaCoCo plugin] Overall coverage: class: 0, method: 0, line: 0, branch: 0, instruction: 0`
```

This is how my Jenkins configuration for Jacoco looks like:

[image]

Comment: Notice the line `Number of found exec files for pattern **/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec: 0` in your Jenkins log - you need to understand why there is no such file, which requires to look on the build log far above this line.

Comment: @Godin Just got success there. Actually the build dir was different then the jenkins job's workspace.

Comment: Also changed exec file location to `**/jacoco.exec`, better you follow what plugin suggests.

Comment: Then to be a good StackOverflow citizen please either remove your question, either post a proper answer on it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: This might happen to the others as well hence answering it would be helpful for the others.

Answer (score 1):

In My case it was failing to get the exec file.

This is because my build directory was different then Jenkins job's WORKSPACE. When i changed the build dir to the WORKSPACE, the magic happened.

Comment: hi, could you please specify the changes you made. Am receiving the same error

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee, i think my Jenkins workspace was different than the default $WORKSPACE. you can try giving the absolute path to the .exec file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using jacocoant 0.6 and the jaCoCo plugin for jenkins was 2.2.0.
From the jaCoCo plugin github page:

> Version 2.0.0 and higher requires using JaCoCo 0.7.5 or newer, if your projects still use JaCoCo 0.7.4, the plugin will not display any code-coverage numbers any more! In this case please use version 1.0.19 until you can update jacoco in your codebase.
>   https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Jacoco plugin is 1.0.19, but I am using Jacoco-maven-plugin 0.7.9 , which it is not compatible.

So, after change Jacoco-maven-plugin to 0.7.4.x. I get correct coverage on Jenkins